# How do I list only source code files when I type ls on OSX? 

Tags: macos, terminal, shell, zsh, ls

when I type ls, I don't want to see .o files because everytime I ls, It see X.cpp X.h X.o, how do I not list .o files?

Answer (score 3):

OS X's BSD `ls` does not support the `-I` argument present in GNU ls to filter file types.

You can run the following expression that returns all files in the current directory that don't have a `.o` extension, and otherwise prints the same format as `ls -l`:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 ! -name '*.o' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -dl
```

You can create a function for this in your `~/.zprofile` so you can run it by typing `lso <extension>`:

```
function lso {
    find * -maxdepth 0 ! -name "*.$1" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -dl
}
```

It's not suitable as a complete `ls` substitute, as it doesn't support arguments.

Sample output:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 danielbeck  staff    0  2 Sep 12:52 pi.c
-rw-r--r--  1 danielbeck  staff    0  2 Sep 12:52 pi.o
-rw-r--r--  1 danielbeck  staff  278 31 Aug 06:52 pi.py
-rw-r--r--  1 danielbeck  staff    0  2 Sep 12:52 pi.pyc

$ lso
-rw-r--r--  1 danielbeck  staff    0  2 Sep 12:52 pi.c
-rw-r--r--  1 danielbeck  staff  278 31 Aug 06:52 pi.py
-rw-r--r--  1 danielbeck  staff    0  2 Sep 12:52 pi.pyc
```

Comment: maybe you could try piping it to grep -v?   ls | grep -v ".o"

Comment: Can you please try to parametrize this using bash parameters?

IBM tutorial to do this seems very complicated. Sorry.

Comment: @snihalani, are we talking about `bash` or `zsh`? Not much difference though...

Comment: @snihalani, I don't know how does the notifications system work, but... I've edited the function to take a parameter (e.g. `lso o`).

Answer (score 0):

If you've `setopt extended_glob`, you can do something like `ls -ld ^*.o` and maybe assign that to an alias of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

@cYrus is correct that the BSD `ls -I ...` filter option is not supported. However here's a quick-and-dirty hack that postprocesses `ls -F` output to exclude directories, symbolic links, sockets, whiteouts, FIFOs:

```
ls -1F | grep -v '[/@=%|]'
```

(Note: obviously this relies on assuming those special characters don't occur in filenames, which is not 100% reliable like a `find`-based approach.)